# How to check if specific id is called from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a MainContent div which contains main content of the website which could be loaded from ajax.

how can i find out if `$("#MainContent").load("someUrl")` was called, so i am able to push new history state to the webbrowser?

Comment: `$("#MainContent").load("someUrl", function() { /* do your thing here */ })`

Comment: Is there not a common function where `$("#MainContent").load("someUrl")` is called from to update the view? If so, you should just manage the history before or after that.

Comment: I just want to see if there are a way to avoid doing this for every single load call

Comment: Then, a good starting point would be to look at [jQuery.Callbacks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)

Comment: yes, thatks a lot :)

Comment: Great, let me know when you figured out a way.

Comment: I end up making a gloabal function, which i call and in that function after i load, i just going to push the history state

Comment: @Timsen That's the way to handle it

Answer (score 1):

Like LSletty said, if you want to know when it is called use the handler from .load() itself:

```
$("#MainContent").load("path/content.html", function(){
      // Do stuff when load is called ...
});
```

More info here: [jQuery load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

To take action after completion I would use the **.done()** handler.

Use it in the following way:

```
$("#MainContent").load("path/content.html").done(function(){
  // Do stuff when load is done ...
});
```

***From jQuery docs:***

> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved.

More info here: [deferred.done() jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)